# Protractor - Find an element in a mat-list

Tags: html, angular, typescript, protractor

I'm doing some automation tests with protractor and I am stuck with a case.
I want to find a mat-list-item that contains a particular text, in this case "Automation A".

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  Might you please [edit] your question to include your HTML as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's requested here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
element(by.xpath('//mat-list-item[contains(.,"Automation A")]'))
```